# C# byte operations optimization: how to get dword from byte[] array

Tags: c#, .net, micro-optimization

Is it possible to get 4 bytes from byte[] array in one operation ?

That means instead of:

```
var octet_a = bytes[i++];
var octet_b = bytes[i++];
var octet_c = bytes[i++];
var octet_d = bytes[i++];
```

get something like

```
Int32 b4= Get4Bytes(i);
i=i+4;
```

Comment: Do you need to do it once, or are you doing it repeatedly at multiple locations in the buffer?

Comment: You can achieve this with `unsafe` code.

Comment: I need it repedeatly. But with back steps. So "in once" describes it better :)

Comment: Try the `ToInt32` Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netframework-4.7#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use BitConverter. as it actually uses unsafe approach to convert byte array to number if possible.

```
var dword = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i);
```

This will be optimized by jitter once it executes first time. if you try similar approaches yourself you wouldn't get much better performance.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you can use `BitConverter` which will definitely do this much better than you can, but in case you still want to know how it's done:

```
public unsafe int Get4Bytes(byte[] bytes, int index)
{
    fixed (byte* b = &bytes[index])
    {
        var v = (int*)b;
        return *v;
    }
}
```

First we get a pointer to the index byte `b` using `fixed`. Since C# is a managed language, the runtime can move memory around whenever it feels like it. We use `fixed` to tell the runtime not to move `bytes` while we're doing unsafe operations against the memory.

Once inside fixed, `b` is currently a `byte*` (a pointer to a byte), but you want 4 bytes, so we cast it to a `int*` (pointer to an int). Note that it's still the same value. Then we de-reference the pointer to get the actual integer value. (`*v`)